# Commenting Clojure within Binding Vector

Tags: clojure

I've noticed that the comment macro doesn't work from within a binding vector like so:

```
(let [a "first string"
      (comment 
      b (range 10)
      c [\a \b \c]
      )
      d "another string"]
  (str a " and " d))
```

Besides placing a semicolon in front of each line in the comment block, are there any other ways to comment several bindings within a binding vector that expects an even number of arguments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `#_` reader macro, which will make the reader completely ignore the next form:

```
(let [a "first string"
      #_( 
      b (range 10)
      c [\a \b \c]
      )
      d "another string"]
  (str a " and " d))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for such a quick response!

Answer (score 5):

mtyaka's answer is the best, but of course you can also do:

```
(let [a "first string"
      _ (comment 
      b (range 10)
      c [\a \b \c]
      )
      d "another string"]
  (str a " and " d))
```